# AJAX returns data twice on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Instead of redirecting the user to a new page, I want to add an overlay over the form. Somehow, the following code returns the overlay twice.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#form_informations').submit(function () 
    {
        $.get('php/formulaires.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data)
        {
            $('#form_informations').append('<div id="conf_informations" class="confirm"><p><img src="img/check.png" /><br /><?=FORMULAIRE_SAUVEGARDE;?></p></div>');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The id `#form_informations` is only used once.

For now, the second overlay is not created in `php/formulaires.php` because the file is empty as I have not started parsing the data.

Why is this happening? I don't see where this second overlay is coming from.

This is the HTML form:

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="form_informations" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- form here -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit_general" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: try `e.preventDefault` in your submit handler

Comment: @user2310289 since return false is used there is no need for that

Comment: oops - wipes dirt from glasses

Comment: is there a chance of a double submit? can you add a `console.log('submit')` in your submit handler and check whether it is logged twice

Comment: if it is called twice then use a `console.trace()` to find the stack trace of the method call and share it

Comment: @ArunPJohny I only get one submit logged

Comment: whether `conf_informations` is the overlay element? also while logging it may not log the logs in different lines since the messages are the same - it may show a counter next to the logged message

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $('#form_informations').submit(function () {
        consol.log('submit', ++counter)
        $.get('php/formulaires.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('#form_informations').append('<div id="conf_informations" class="confirm"><p><img src="img/check.png" /><br /><?=FORMULAIRE_SAUVEGARDE;?></p></div>');
        });
        return false;
    });
});` for logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can add some code like this in the submit function

```
if(!$("#conf_informations").size()) {
    $.get... //your get request here
}
```

---

Final solution

```
if(!$("#conf_informations").length()) {
    $.get... //your get request here
}
```

Comment: By changing `.size` to `.length`, I've avoided the duplicate div